# Why was there no "Improve Edit" option?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

I was reviewing [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17352931). The edit does improve the question, but I thought it would be better for the code at the end to be indent formatted instead of using backticks (my question isn't whether or not this is the case though).

I wasn't given the option to improve the edit though; only Approve, Reject and Skip.

Why wasn't I given the option to improve the edit?

Comment: Probably, because the question is deleted.

Comment: Because it's a deleted post. Wait a while until the system invalidates the review task.

Comment: Oh, while that kind of makes sense. Seems odd though that the system must have realized that it was deleted (since it dropped the option to improve), but still left it in the queue.

Comment: I like the universal edit summary. I guess they use it for every edit :|

Comment: @Honk Ya, I wasn't too keen on that, but I didn't think that was a good reason to reject it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I wouldn't reject a good edit because of a bad summary, but I don't appreciate that behavior either. (This doesn't mean that I consider the edit in question a good edit.)

Comment: There's a difference between an *incorrect* summary and simply a poor quality one. This falls into the latter bucket, and isn't in itself sufficient reason to reject. However, when the edit summary is a total lie, then that is reason enough to reject the edit.